# After update: Property named 'model' in my mongoose schemas causes trouble

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

After updating packages of my Nest.js project some of my mongoose schemas stoped to compile. Following error is thrown:

> Interface 'LeasingValue' incorrectly extends interface 'Document<any,
> any, any>'. Types of property 'model' are incompatible.

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ <ModelType = Model<unknown,
> {}, {}, {}, Document<unknown, {}, unknown> & Required<{ _id: unknown;
> }>, any>>(name: string): ModelType; <ModelType = Model<any, {}, {},
> {}, any, any>>(): ModelType; }'

In fact there is a property 'model' in LeasingValue that is of type string. That is suddenly not allowed anymore causing probleme with a mongoose property named 'model' on the documents.

I think I oversee something and there should be an easy fix other than downgrading again. Before the update it was possible to have mongoose schemas with a property called 'model'.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is rather simple. Instead of using Document as type for extending interface to use with mongoose schemas just use the type HydratedDocument.
The HydratedDocument represents the type you get when you call

```
new Model(...)
```

The actual structure looks like this:

```
export interface FirstTplImagePerModel extends HydratedDocument<any> {
    ...
    model: string
    ...
}
```

The property named 'model' is possible now.